# What is wrong with this code - maze in C?

Tags: c, maze

Well, I am trying to create a maze in C. When I try running the code (picture below) the output is `101010101010` and it doesn't stop until I use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>.

n - for example: n = 3 ->

```
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 1
```

Maze has size 2n+1 x 2n+1 because I decided to create an array which contains both numbers and walls. It is how it is supposed to look like:

```
x x x x x x x
x 1   1   1 x 
x           x
x 1   1   1 x
x           x
x 1   1   1 x
x x x x x x x
```

The blank spaces are supposed to be walls.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 4;      
    int maze[(2 * n) + 1][(2 * n) + 1];
    
    // creating maze
    for (int i = 0; i < (2 * n) + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (2 * n) + 1; j++) {
            maze[(2 * i) - 1][(2 * j) - 1] = 1;
            if (2 * 1 == 0 || 2 * j == 0)
                maze[2 * i][2 * j] = 0;
            else
                maze[2 * i][2 * j] = 1;
            
            printf("%d", maze[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:
[image: output]

Comment: What do you suppose this line does when `i` and `j` are `0`? `maze[(2*i) -1][(2*j)-1] = 1;` https://godbolt.org/z/7MEExj4qG Theother assignments inside the loop will also access the array out of bounds because of the `2*i` and `2*j`.

Comment: `maze[(2*i) -1][(2*j)-1]` and `maze[2*i][2*j]` will break the array bounds. The iterators `i` and `j` are already doing the `2*` business. So you just need `maze[i][j] = 1;`

Comment: There is a typo with `2*1 == 0` which I guess is supposed to be `2*i == 0` (which anyway is probably still wrong).

Comment: Think about what the `-1` does when `i == 0` or `j == 0` in  `maze[(2*i) -1][(2*j)-1] = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- The code has undefined behavior because you write beyond the end of the matrix in `maze[(2 * i) - 1][(2 * j) - 1] = 1;`, `maze[2 * i][2 * j] = 0;` and `maze[2 * i][2 * j] = 1;`

Since `i` and `j` vary from `0` to `2 * n`, you should just refer to `maze[i][j]`.

- Furthermore, the test `if (2 * 1 == 0 || 2 * j == 0)` probably has a typo and should be changed to

  ```
  if (i == 0 || j == 0)
  ```
- You should output a newline after each row.